# How to use Gulp with PM2?

Tags: gulp, pm2, gulp-watch

I'm using `Gulp` to compile and minify `SCSS`, `Pug`, `JSX` and that sort of things. So in the development process as usual I'm opening the terminal window and typing `gulp` and it watches my files. But I have to keep open the terminal window and Gulp tab, otherwise my files don't be compiled.

I'm using `PM2` too. When I wanna start a `Node job` I just write `pm2 start file.js --watch` and `pm2 startup` in order to start the script on operating system opening. I wanna do the same thing for Gulp. I've tried like `pm2 start gulpfile.js --watch`, but it doesn't work.

How can I use Gulp with PM2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert in `gulp`, but you can execute your `gulp` command via `pm2` by defining it in the process file at your project root.

**ecosystem.json**

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": <name_of_your_app>,
            "script": "gulp"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, from terminal, run `$ pm2 start ecosystem.json`. You can also define `watch` options at that process file. See [this](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/#auto-restart-apps-on-file-change) for more details.

Comment: That JSON file works perfectly. I didn't know PM2 has an option like that. I don't know why but if you run PM2 with a `--watch` parameter, it enters an infinite loop. It compiles same files again and again. Maybe the reason is that I've already had a watch task in Gulp. But without `--watch` parameter everything looks fine. When you change a source file it'll watch and compile. And if you don't have a global Gulp module installed you have to change your script like `"script": "node_modules/.bin/gulp"`.

Comment: Yes, if you delegate the `watch` task to `gulp`, then you don't need to watch the files using `pm2` [ozgrozer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340552/ozgrozer)